# Jwplayer setCurrentTime Not working

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I am using the Jwplayer to play videos on my site.
No I am opening the Poll popups on some time intervals and on closing of the popup setting the Current Time of the player.

I am using _player.setCurrentTime(time).

This is not working as expected . Because when I am using the time like :
_player.setCurrentTime(38) then its playing the video from 35 seconds.

its working fine for the following:
_player.setCurrentTime(40)//playing video from 40 seconds
_player.setCurrentTime(35)//playing video from 35 seconds

Only Issue with the time that is not divisible of 5.

So what I need to do to fix this issue?

Plz help.
Dalvir

Answer (score 0):

setCurrentTime is not a valid event in our API. onTime is, though - http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference, where are you running this?

Comment: Do you have a link to where you are running this ?